# Filling a var from a callback result?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Started playing with node, and still quite new to it. I have the following code, is it possible to return "results" from where I want to in x?

```
function dbRequest(sql) {
    var x;
    var dbResults = client.query(sql, function (err,results,fields) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        x = results;
        client.end(); 
    });
    // I want x here to return what is in results.
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. At least not in the manner you tried it.

Most likely, the call `client.query()` will launch an asyncronous request for node. That in turn means, that the code execution will continue immediately and therefore, will return the value of `x` before it can get filled by the callback.

A pretty convinient way to deal with that kind of stuff is, to pass in another callback method which you need to define yourself (if you want to do certain things with the result)

For instance:

```
function dbRequest(sql, cb) {
    var dbResults = client.query(sql,function(err,results,fields) {
               if (err) {
                   throw err;
               }
                    if (typeof cb === 'function') {
                       cb(results);
                    }

                    client.end(); 
           });
}
```

and then call it like

```
dbRequest('select * from foo', function(data) {
    // do something with data
});
```